# Sending a Data Range to Another Data Range in Matlab without a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

So here is what I have :

an `index : [3;4;5;6;7;8;9]`
I have a vector that corresponds to that index :

```
inVector = [10;20;30;40;50;60;70;80;90]
```

What I want is that I get the mean of every 3 rows in the invector. Hence,

```
outVector = mean(inVector[index - 2 : index]);
```

Hence, outVector now has `[20;30;40;50;60;70;80];`

Comment: What's the use of `index`?

Comment: It's just an index that I traverse and then go through the corresponding 3 preceding rows in inVector to get the mean with.

Comment: IF index is always `x:end`, you can look into `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary `index`, you can do it using `cumsum`:

```
N = 3;
aux = cumsum([0; inVector(:)]);
result = (aux(index+1)-aux(index-N+1))/N;
```

If `index` always consists of consecutive indices, it's easier to use `conv` (since a moving average is a convolution with a rectangular window):

```
N = 3;
result = conv(inVector,ones(1,N)/N,'valid');
```